# Saving any information in list view without using database in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a reminder application without using a database. How can I save reminders (like reminder 1, reminder 2 goes on up to 3) in list view items so that by clicking any list view item, I can open that reminder set by me earlier?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) available in Android.  May be simply storing in files will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well just for three reminders I might go for SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preferences for that.

Use below code for save data into shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString(MY_NAME, "Sai");
prefsEditor.putString(MY_WALLPAPER, "f664.PNG");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Use below code for get data from shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_NAME, "nothing");
String wallPaper = myPrefs.getString(MY_WALLPAPER, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[Internal Sotrage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

[External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

[SqLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

[Network Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw)